# What does the word "suggestion" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was recently speaking about a design challenge. This person felt that a side table was required and while I felt no side table was required, I said a shelf could also be used. This person then said that I "suggested" a shelf. I clarified saying I was not "suggesting" it and I was just throwing out an idea. I explained that when I hear the word "suggestion" the implication is that I am a proponent of that particular idea. This person then insisted we look at the dictionary.

The definition was:

> an idea or plan put forward for consideration.
>   "here are some suggestions for tackling the problem"
>
> synonyms:   proposal, proposition, motion, submission, recommendation; advice, counsel, exhortation, hint, tip, clue, tip-off, idea, piece of advice.
>
> ”there are some suggestions for tackling this problem"

This did not bring us any closer to a resolution. I understand that the word suggestion can (probably) be used if you are not a proponent of the idea (in some bizarre and unusual cases), so I do not *entirely* disagree with the other person's definition. But I don't think my definition is incorrect either.

However, the other person accused me of playing word games and said my definition (that it implies I am a proponent of the idea) is indisputably incorrect. When I asked whether my definition could at the very least be construed as "reasonable". This person disagreed.

Please let me know what your views are.

1. Is my definition correct? Is the other person's? or are both definitions reasonable?
2. If the other person's definition is correct, is my definition so far out that it is justifiably considered to be "game playing"?

Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing in the definition of the word that you quoted that backs up your premise. Per the quoted definition (it would be helpful if you cited it's source), your "throwing out an idea" *is* a suggestion. To defend your claim, you need to provide a dictionary definition (somewhere) that equates *suggestion* with *personal belief*. (As it is, you have taken a step to proving yourself wrong.) Otherwise, you can use the word to mean whatever you want it to mean—but you won't be able to effectively communicate with somebody else if your meaning doesn't match theirs.

Comment: Well the dictionary uses the synonym "recommendation". Is it not usually implied that you are a proposing or are in favor of, a suggestion you make? Doesn't a "suggestion" imply support from the "suggester"? How does one suggest something as part of a brainstorming discussion but clearly express one is not in "favor" of their own "suggestion"?

Comment: A recommendation doesn't imply investment either. I could recommend or suggest that a serial killer dispatch somebody in a certain way. That wouldn't mean I'd want them to. I have never thought of a suggestion as anything other than value-neutral. It is an objective proposal, that I may or may not be invested in. Brainstorming is essentially about throwing out random ideas—even ones you've given no thought to. The point of brainstorming is that you don't censor yourself. Even if you think a suggestion is bad, you should still present it as a possibility.

Comment: In the scenario you describe, you _suggested_ a compromise between your colleague's wish for a table and your wish for none.

Comment: Suggestion connotes avocacy and engagement. Otherwise it would be impossible to *strongly* suggest something.

Comment: You suggested something.  Why are you so bent out of shape about what he said?  What word would you have used instead??

Comment: (Note that, absent wording that implies otherwise, "suggestion" does not carry any pejorative implication.  It's about as neutral a word as one can use in a discussion.)

Answer (score 3):

The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suggest) defines *suggest* as

> Put forward for consideration

and says that its origins are

> Early 16th century: from Latin suggest- ‘suggested, prompted’, from the verb suggerere, from sub- ‘from below’ + gerere ‘bring’.

This does not imply, necessarily, any great commitment by the originator of the suggestion to the solution or course of action being suggested.

In normal use *suggest* and *suggestion* can range in meaning from a very vague or even hesitant contribution to a debate such as "This is just a suggestion, but could we look for a simpler solution?" to a very definite proposal such as "I suggest that we take a vote on this!". Paticularly if the hesitant suggestion comes from a junior member of the team and the definite one comes from the person with the highest status.

Making a suggestion does not mean that the person making it is a strong proponent of it, it is even possible to "suggest" something you would not support in order to get others to look at a problem differently, this is done sometimes to move deadlocked discussions on.

I think you may have encountered *suggest* only in the context of its accusatory sense: ("*Are you suggesting that I have been embezzling funds? How dare you!*") and, therefore, feel that it always carries connotations of forcefulness and criticism which it does not.

'Suggestion' has a much wider and, generally much less formal, use than "proposal" and can be used with adjectives such as "tentative", "helpful", "powerful", "forceful" and many others giving a wide range of force. I agree with your colleague that you definitely "suggested" the shelf because you put the idea forward for consideration and  am quite surprised that you thought his use of "suggest" implied critcism of you.

Comment: What somewhat complicates the question of how much commitment to X is implied by suggesting to do X is that one can, at the same time, have no commitment at all to X being **the** thing to do, and a very strong commitment to X being worthy of serious consideration as one of the options. Also, it might be debatable whether *suggest* is used literally in 'I suggest that we take a vote on this!' or as a polite softening of *insist*.

Comment: @jsw29 I'll agree that 'suggest' in 'I suggest we take a vote on this" can be a polite softening of another word but I believe that the word being softened is "propose" rather than "insist". People who have (or believe themselves to have) a lot of power in a given set of circumstances may use many forms of words but will expect that the other parties will do what the person with the power wants whatever they say. This does not, really. affect the interpretaion of the language, just the power dymanics in the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary definition is fine, but the usage of the term is more nuanced.

Consider the sense of "you suggested" when the stress is placed on each word.

- Stressing "you" leads to the generic sense, where the possibility of using a shelf was raised by you. Instead of *possibility*, one could use the words *proposal* or even *suggestion* without implying any commitment to the idea on your part. It's in this sense that your colleague's statements should be taken.
- Stressing "suggested" narrows the semantic range of the word to something more akin to a vested interest. That's the sense that you appear to have taken your colleague's comments.

Unfortunately, off-the-cuff utterances can often be intended one way and taken another. In your example, both positions can be argued, but the generic sense tends to dominate unless special effort is made (and perceived) to invoke the narrower sense.